# htaccess rewrite from url with query strings to directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have switched my site from drupal to wordpress and some url's with query strings and some urls do not exist anymore.

Now I want make a redirect from old query string urls to a directory on the new page.

The path with the query string looks like so:

https://example.com/ausstattung-service-und-extras/tresor-wertfach?page=1

I have try something but I can't find the solution.

```
RewriteRule ^ausstattung-service-und-extras/(.*) /klinikverzeichnis [R=301,L]
```

This works only without query strings.

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you actually mean by "this works only without query strings". Actually the query string is _not_ part of the pattern a `RewriteRule` works on. TO access or evaluate query string components you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable inside a `RewriteCond`. There are many examples for that here on SO and the official documentation of the apache http servers rewriting module clearly explains that.

Comment: hi, i need to rewrite from https://example.com/ausstattung-service-und-extras/tresor-wertfach?page=1 to https://example.com/ausstattung i have a lot urls with query strings like example and all url's should rewrite to https://example.com/ausstattung

Comment: Repeating what you already wrote does not help to clearify things, sorry. Did you understand what I wrote in my comment? What is your reply to that?

Comment: ok i think i understand it it works with RewriteCond? ok i found something like this RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=(.*)
RewriteRule index.html  %1 but I don't know how the code should looks like

Comment: I have the impression that you don't really know what you are doing and have not taken a single look into the documentation I referred to. That should always be the first step to start reading instead of asking here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html That documentation is of great quality and comes with good examples. If you still have questions afterwards, _then_ is the time to ask here.

Comment: for all other people who looks for a solution here is my code: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ausstattung-service-und-extras/(.*)$ /klinikverzeichnis [L,R=301,QSD]

Comment: OK, great to see that you found what you are looking for, maybe my hint to take a look at the information did help to understand how things work. Looking at your code I'd say so you were looking for a redirection that is only applied if some page is explicitly requested, since otherwise you could simply ignore the query string... Sorry, but that fact was absolutely not clear from your question...